# Unix command line: how to add double quotes to a word?

Tags: linux, unix, sed, command

i have a text file "names.txt" that contains a list of words like so :

```
Adidas
Android
Bluetooth
Minaret
Mushroom
acorn
airplane
amazon
```

i want this file to be exactly like :

```
"Adidas" = "";
"Android" = "";
"Bluetooth" = "";
"Minaret" = "";
"Mushroom" = "";
"acorn" = "";
"airplane" = "";
"amazon" = "";
```

Any idea how to accomplish this ? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this sed?

```
$ sed -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/" = "";/' file
"Adidas" = "";
"Android" = "";
"Bluetooth" = "";
"Minaret" = "";
"Mushroom" = "";
"acorn" = "";
"airplane" = "";
"amazon" = "";
```

It replaces the beginning of the line (`^`) with `"` and the end of line (`$`) with `" = "";`. So it eventually adds `"` at the beginning and `" = "";` at the end.

Use `sed -i.bak '...'` to in place edit.

---

You can also use bash for this:

```
while read line
do
    printf "%s%s%s\n" '"' $line '" = "";'
done < file
```

---

Or awk:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s%s\n", "\"", $0, "\" = \"\";"}' file
```

Comment: no need for printf, could just use normal print `awk '{print "\""$0"\" = \"\";"}' file`

Comment: Yeah I know, thanks, only that I prefer how it looks `{printf "%s%s%s\n", "\"", $0, "\" = \"\";"}`, as it gives a best control of the leading and trailing strings to write.

Answer (score 2):

Use this `sed` command:

```
sed 's/.*/"&" = "";/'
```

To modify the file in place, you can do this:

```
sed 's/.*/"&" = "";/' filename > tmp && mv tmp filename
```

(pick a temporary file name that doesn't already exist; I often use `$$`, the current shell's process ID) or:

```
sed -i.bak 's/.*/"&" = "";/' filename
```

The latter copies the original file to `filename.bak`.

Comment: +1 I like the trick with `.*` and the explanation you provide.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v ORS='" = "";\n' '$1="\""$1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk way

```
awk '$0="\""$0"\" = \"\";"' file
```

Sed way

```
sed 's/.*/"&" = "";/' file
```